# C++ Constexpr Function

Tags: c++, constexpr

could anyone help me to understand why this code snippet won't compile?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>
#include <string_view>

constexpr auto Fields()
{
    using namespace std::string_view_literals;

    return std::tuple(
        std::tuple("campo_1"sv, 123),
        std::tuple("campo_2"sv, 456),
        std::tuple("campo_3"sv, 890),
        std::tuple("campo_4"sv, 136));
}

template<typename Tuple>
constexpr auto ProcessTupleElement(Tuple &&tuple)
{
    //constexpr auto ccb = std::get<1>(tuple); // 1 uncomment to get an error
    //char sx[ccb]; // 1 uncomment to get an error
    //(void)sx;
    return std::get<1>(tuple);
}

template<typename Tuple>
constexpr auto IterateTupleImpl(Tuple &&t)
{
    return ProcessTupleElement(std::get<0>(std::forward<Tuple>(t)));
}

template<typename Tuple>
constexpr auto IterateTuple(Tuple &&t)
{
    return IterateTupleImpl(std::forward<Tuple>(t));
}

int main()
{
    constexpr auto aa = IterateTuple(Fields()); // 2
    char sx[aa];
    (void)sx;
    return 0;
}
```

The code is just for testing purposes, I'm trying to figure out why in `main` function (comment "2") I'm able to define a constexpr variable which I then use to define a C-array size, but trying to do the same in function `ProcessTupleElement` (marked whit comment "1") I'm receiving a compiler error saying that:
`prog.cc:19:20: error: '* & tuple' is not a constant expression`
`19 |     constexpr auto ccb = std::get<1>(tuple);`
`prog.cc:20:10: error: size of array is not an integral constant-expression`
`20 |     char sx[ccb]; // 1`

As extra information, I'm compiling with GCC (C++ 17).
My idea behind this test is to iterate in compile time a tuple like the one defined inside `Fields` function to test whether it has repeated names, but I can't manage to solve a previous problem, I.E. `constexpr`ness of function + variables.

Answer (score 5):

argument are not constexpr (even when use with constexpr at call site).

Remember that constexpr function might be called as regular function.

Btw, you might have simplified your example to

```
constexpr int identity(int n)
{
    // constexpr int i = n; // Invalid
    return n;
}

constexpr int the_answer = identity(42);
```